# Python Flet cannot align text to center

Tags: python, flet

Hello i am a beginner in Flet module my goal is center the text.

According to documentation there is a text_align property in text widget.

I tried to use it but not worked.

My code:

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Zirinus X Edition"
    page.scroll = "adaptive "
    title_text = ft.Text(
        value=f"Zirinus X",
        size=60,
        weight=ft.FontWeight.W_100,
        text_align="CENTER"
    )
    page.add(title_text)
    page.update()



ft.app(target=main)
```

UPDATE

I throught i found the solution but still not centering the text.

Code:

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Zirinus X Edition"
    page.scroll = "adaptive "
    title_text = ft.Text(
        text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER,
        value=f"Zirinus X",
        size=60,
        weight=ft.FontWeight.W_100,
    )
    page.add(title_text)
    page.update()



ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/text/) for text widget

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `page.horizontal_alignment` and `page.vertical_alignment` inside the main function. Here is the modified code.

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):

    # these two lines will align the text center in the app
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    # adding the text in the app
    page.add(
        ft.Text(
            value="Hello World!",       # Adding the text
            size=32,                    # Increasing the size of the text
            weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD   # it will bold the text
        )
    )

ft.app(target=main)
```

Don’t add `page.scroll` and `page.update()` in every code. You need `page.update()` when you are changing anything while running the application. For example, changing the text by clicking a button. Otherwise, it has no use. And if you don’t want to scroll the app page, remove the `page.scroll`. Accoding to your code, it do nothing here.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the `Text` widget inside a `Row` and center align.

The code would look like this:

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Zirinus X Edition"
    page.scroll = "adaptive "
    title_text = ft.Row(
        controls=[
            ft.Text(
                text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER,
                value=f"Zirinus X",
                size=60,
                weight=ft.FontWeight.W_100,
            )
        ],
        alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    )
    page.add(title_text)

ft.app(target=main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flet widgets size to their content, or to their parent if you make the widget `expand=True`.   So to centre text in a `Text` widget you have to set its `width` to a specific value or place it in a control with a width that is either set or changes with screen width (like a `ResponsiveRow`)

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'page.horizontal_alignment' argument.

```
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.horizontal_alignment = 'CENTER'
    page.title = "Zirinus X Edition"
    page.scroll = "adaptive "
    title_text = ft.Text(
        value=f"Zirinus X",
        size=60,
        weight=ft.FontWeight.W_100,
        text_align="CENTER"
    )
    page.add(title_text)
    page.update()

ft.app(target=main)
```